# Оператор ++ к указателю

Tags: указатели, c++, visual-c++

VC++ 2010 выдает

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'x' was corrupted.

Происходит из-за строки "pchar++"(увеличения значения указателя на 1), но это же допустимая операция. Что сделать, чтобы ошибки не выдавало?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(char *pchar);

int main()
{
    char *pchar, x;
    pchar = &x;
    *pchar = 'a';
    func(pchar);
    cout << *pchar;

}

void func(char *pchar)
{
    char *pch;
    *pchar = 'b';
    pchar++;
    *pchar = 'c';
}
```

Comment: @Art, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Не писать, куда неположено. pchar ссылается на переменную `char x`. Пишите туда 'b' -- нормально. Пишите в следующий за x байт 'c' -- что-то портите. vc++ обижается и начинает ругаться.

Comment: Но это же разрешенная операция.

Comment: Какая операция разрешена? Увеличение pchar? Да. Запись в память (в стеке -- переменная x -- локальная) вне переменной x, х.з. куда? Нет.
И вообще, это что? Лабораторная работа на тему "срыв стека"?

Comment: Что значит "всё работает"? Это значит, что Вы портите что-то такое, что не проявляется при работе Вашей программы. Это временно. Если не будете писать аккуратней -- когда-нибудь скажется. Такие ошибки иногда очень трудно обнаружить. (Ну а про new Вам уже написали). И ещё. Фраза "выделяется память под указатель" в данном контексте неправильна. В Вашем случае под указатель pchar выделяется 4б (если 32бит система) во фрейме стека, резервируемом процедурой main. Это память, которую занимает сам указатель.

Comment: Да, про New не знал. 
Просто в книжке Шилдта в главе "Указатели" ничего про New не говорится. New описывается через две главы спустя.

Comment: Сделайте переменную **x** хотя бы **short** (размером в 2 байта)  и **в этом виде** программа отработает. 

Строгий какой и экономный компилятор у Вас... Обычно (на gcc) это IMHO прокатит (м.б. потрете один байтик (запишите туда 'c') у первого параметра func()).

Comment: Это не компилятор, это рантаймовая проверка. Лучше не short, а нормальный массив char )

Comment: @insolor, это же понятно (хотя наличие такого рантайм предполагает некие действия компилятора). Расценивайте комментарий скорее как шутку, а не попытку обучения автора.

Answer (score 3):

Вы смещаетесь в область, дальше чем отведено переменной и спрашиваете почему происходит ошибка? Представьте, что к вам через стену проломится сосед, просто попить чаю... Тоже самое чувствует и та переменная, которая в стеке и на которую вы лезете!

Сори за каламбур.

Кстати, если хотите поиграться с ++ применимо к указателям, сделайте что-то вроде:

```
char b = new char[200];
b++;
```

Comment: Это не C#. Надо так:

    char* b = new char[200];

Comment: Ой, сори... Давно на плюсах не писал :).

Comment: или так: char *pchar, x[100]; pchar = x;

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
char *pchar;
pchar = new char[2];
*pchar='a';
*pchar='b';
pchar++;
*pchar='c';
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы пишете `pchar++` вы перемещаетесь за пределы аллоцированной (выделенной) под `pchar` памяти и вторгаетесь в область которую занимает переменная `x`.

Для того, чтобы этого не происходило нужно аллоцировать под pchar не 1 элемент, а хотя бы 2

```
pchar=new char[2];
```

тогда pchar++ будет указывать на pchar[1]

Comment: Только не вторгаетесь, а выходите. См. перед func(pchar) pchar устанавливаем на x. Видимо в оригинале func() по указателю меняет значение x с 'a' на 'b'.

Для "**усиления эффекта**" автор *решил добавить* 'c' в следующий байт, и упал...

Вы же @Barmaley, в своем ответе рассматриваете другой случай (видимо методологически верный, но другой).